# Are there any fluorophores with lifetimes in the micro to milli second range?

Tags: databases, fluorescence

I'm looking for a fluorophore with exceptionally long lifetime to use in an oxygen optode (the longer the lifetime the less timing precision needed in the electronics).

So far the longest I have encountered in my searches is 600nS for Ru(bpy)3[PF6]2 found in [this table](http://www.iss.com/resources/reference/data_tables/LifetimeDataFluorophores.html) but that resource appears less than exhaustive; Is there a more comprehensive data sources available where I could compare lifetimes and relevant wavelengths for all known fluorophors?

.. also just to clarrify the fluorophore needs to undergo quenching by oxygen ...

Comment: Then you're rather looking for phosphorescence.

Comment: Uranyl ion has a fluorescence lifetime of about 1.5 microseconds: Catalysis of ionic reactions by polyelectrolytes. III. Quenching of uranyl ion fluorescence by iron(II) ions in poly(vinylsulfonic acid) solution, Herbert MorawetzIssam A. I. Taha
Cite this: J. Am. Chem. Soc. 1971, 93, 4, 829-833
Publication Date:February 1, 1971
https://doi.org/10.1021/ja00733a005

Comment: Thanks, while heartening to find the microseconds lifetime is not out of the realm of possibilities - Uranyl is a bit to exotic for my purposes (the end product needs to be compatible with international and domestic postal services)

Comment: You might consider Europium or Terbium compounds. Eu3+ and Tb3+ complexes can have long lifetimes in the range of hundreds of microseconds to milliseconds (https://www.tcichemicals.com/US/en/c/10226).

Answer (score 1):

According to the article [Indicators for optical oxygen sensors; Michela Quaranta, Sergey M. Borisov, Ingo Klimant](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3514702/pdf/12566_2012_Article_32.pdf)

> Among all the indicators that have been used for optical oxygen sensors, Pt(II) and Pd(II) porphyrins are the mostpopular luminophores since they possess strong phosphorescence at room temperature, moderate to high molar absorption coefficients and large Stokes’shifts. Additionally, phosphorescence lifetimes are rather long (microsecond to millisecond) and can be tuned by varying the nature of the central atom.

They then go on to include a table (Table 3 on page 131) of 36 dyes based on that chemistry, 35 with lifetimes in the microseconds and 1 (PdTFPP) with a lifetime of 1.65 milliseconds.

In relation to my quest for a data source to compare fluorophors I managed to stumble upon the website [fluorophores.org](http://www.fluorophores.tugraz.at/substance/) that currently includes 952 substances and can be filtered by excitation, emission, quantum yield, and lifetime parameters.

Comment: What is your analytical application? You mentioned oxygen optode but where do you plan to use it.

Comment: Inside permeable product packaging to monitor effectiveness of oxygen scavenger / absorber materials in real time.

Comment: Is it something like this commercial product https://www.oxysense.com/how-oxysense-works.html?

Comment: On first glance that appears to be EXACTLY what I need! Do you know of any commercial products that use this in there packaging so I could test it out? I will be contacting the company directly but who knows how long that will take.

Comment: I am afraid not. But I am sure they have something safe. These metal containing fluorophores will be expensive and who knows how safe they are. Do a heavy and deep literature search again.

Comment: Thanks, according to OxySense's patent (US20070243618A1) they use a ruthenium based fluorophore: "The present invention provides a ruthenium-based luminescence indicator composition that includes a tris-4,7-diphenyl-1,10-phenanthroline ruthenium(II) compound and one or more dioctylphthalate dispersed within a gas permeable polyacrylate matrix. The tris-4,7-diphenyl-1,10-phenanthroline ruthenium(II) compound has a fluorescence lifetime that is affected by exposure to one or more gases and exposure to the one or more gases is monitored"

Comment: Great. So you have clues now to see the new directions.